# Squaring a number using return values

Tags: python, function, return, return-value

Okay, so I'm sure this is a pretty simple assignment, but I'm having a lot of trouble with it because online classes suck and I just started coding. Anyways, I'm working on a python assignment where I have to square a number using return values. Here's the instructions:

> Write a function to square a number using return values. Squaring a number means multiplying it by itself (duh). Then make several calls to that function in your start function to test it out. Your square function should only return a value, not print anything.
> For example a function call like
> x = square(5)
> should put the value 25 in x.
> Print out x to be sure your function returns the correct value."

And here's the code I ended with. I'm sure it's not great, but it's a simple assignment that just wants me to return a function- no more, no less. But with the information I was given, I just can't figure it out:

```
def square(x): 
    squared = x * x
    return squared
    print(squared)

print(square(5))
print(square(9))
print(square(8))
#above is just me 'testing' the code. If I don't include it, the checker tells me its wrong.
```

The code works fine when it comes to squaring whatever number I give it, and the code itself includes the return function as stated. However, it says it's wrong and to "Store the return value so you can verify it is correct." I looked in all of the lessons and videos and I can't find anything about storing a return value to verify it. Any help?

P.S. Sorry if the formatting is wrong. I literally just made an account 10 minutes ago because I'm kind of desperate for someone smarter than me to tell me what it is I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Thank you for being honest about asking for help with a homework assignment. What do you expect to happen after the `return` statement in your `square` function? Do you expect the `print(squared)` to be executed? As for "storing the return value" simply assign the result of your `square` function to a variable; e.g., `x = square(4)`. Followed by `print(x)`.

Answer (score 1):

The instructions tell you how to do it:

> For example a function call like `x = square(5)` should put the value `25` in `x`.

So you should write:

```
x = square(5)
print(x)
```

You also shouldn't have `print(squared)` in the function. It's not doing anything because it's after the `return` statement, which ends the function.